# How to use .htaccess to restrict script access from external server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i am trying to achieve this:
i have a directory/folder in my primary domain example.com/scripts.
the folder named script should only be accessed by websites that are subdomain of example.com which means that from any of these websites:

```
admin.example.com,
people.example.com,
etc.example.com,
example.com
```

their pages should be able to call scripts or anything in the /scripts directory e.g

```
<script src="https://example.com/scripts/js/demo.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/scripts/css/demo.css">
```

if for instance a page from anotherdomain.com try to access the /scripts directory, the server responds with 404.

Please help!
thanks.

Comment: You follow a completely wrong approach. Do not first publish something and then try to hold it back. You will never be able to _really_ secure that. Instead use a routing endpoint in those "subdomain hosts", thus being able to limit the access to that folder to a single IP address, your own system. So that from a client side perspective the browser requests the script from the websites own "subdomain" which in turn _internally_ re-routes the request to that folder / host / whatever.

Comment: okay, thanks for ur suggestion but how do i follow this approach?? can you help me with samples... thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "how to follow"? I explained what to do. One does not implement cross domain requests anyway, _all_ requests your client site performs should be against its own host ("subdomain") and nowhere else, you will run into cross domain issues otherwise once you start using https. So instead of sending a request to mainhost/scripts/somescript you send that request to a simple router in the subsomain http server. That router (a simple script) receives the request, does an internal request and forwards the response to the client.

Comment: pls can u help me with sample script of the 'simple router' am not too good with server routing. thank you

Comment: OK, I added an answer, hope that helps. But please note that you will have to implement a solution yourself. We cannot do that for you. And especially you should not simply copy and paste something you read somewhere. You need to understand what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

You follow a completely wrong approach. Do not first publish something and then try to hold it back. You will never be able to really secure that. Instead use a routing endpoint in those "subdomain hosts", thus being able to limit the access to that folder to a single IP address, your own system. So that from a client side perspective the browser requests the script from the websites own "subdomain" which in turn internally re-routes the request to that folder / host / whatever.

There are many solutions for that. Any many explanations of how to do that are found on the internet.

According to your description you have a very simple setup, so do not require any special logic in such routing logic. Instead you want a simple and static mapping. Easiest would be to do that on the level of the http server itself. If you have the proxy module loaded, then you can do something like that to implement a simple forward proxy:

```
ProxyPass /scripts/ http://example.com/scripts/
```

If it is not only scripts served from `http://example.com/scripts/` but also something holding back references then you need to setup a reverse proxy:

```
ProxyPass /scripts/ http://example.com/scripts/
ProxyPassReverse /scripts/ http://example.com/scripts/
```

Best is to place such definitions in the http server configurations of the "subdomains". You can also use dynamic configuration files for such stuff, but that has many disadvantages.

As said there are other solutions. For example you can implement a simple router script, that allows fine tuned authorization management and the like. But you apparently don't need that.

The main goal of all this is:

- do not publish *anything* from http://example.com directly, so block access to it *except* for the subdomains http server(s).
- make *all* client side requests from your "webpages" point to the http host they were served from, so the subdomains http hosts.

The official documentation of the apache http server contains all the information you need. It is of excellent quality and comes with good examples.